# How do I perform a bitwise or (|) for enumerations in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to perform a bitwise or (|) operation to apply multiple enumerations to a variable in PowerShell used by a .NET assembly. However, when the single pipe character to do this I get an `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline` error. How do I assign multiple enumerations in PowerShell?

```cs
    $everyone = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null);
    $fsr = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read;
    $if = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit | [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit;
    $pf = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None;
    $act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow;
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($everyone, $fsr, $if, $pf, $act);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `-bor` [bitwise operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators#bitwise-operators), e.g.:

```
([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor
 [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)

ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
```

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell will provide automatic conversion from strings, so you could also do this:

```
$everyone = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null);
$fsr = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read;
$if = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
$pf = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None;
$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow;
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($everyone, $fsr, $if, $pf, $act);
```

In fact if you wanted it to be significantly less to type (good for quick command line stuff when you don't care about clarity for reading later) you could do it like this:

```
$everyone = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null);
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $everyone, "Read", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done using the `-bOr` operator. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators#bitwise-operators) on bitwise operators.

The code sample above would look like this after `-bOr` is implemented:

```powershell
$everyone = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null);
$fsr = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read;
$if = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bOr [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit;
$pf = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None;
$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow;
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($everyone, $fsr, $if, $pf, $act);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put the two inheritanceflag objects inside an array:

```
$everyone = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null);
$fsr = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read;
$if = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit
$if2 = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit;
$pf = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None;
$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow;
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($everyone, $fsr, ($if,$if2), $pf, $act);
```