# Powershell IE automation how to pass flags to navigate method?

Tags: powershell

How can I pass flags to the InternetExplorer navigate method
Specifically, no cache or read or write to history
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768360%28v%3dvs.85%29

What Ive tried so far, but just basing this off the BrowserNavConstants enum.  Im not sure how one would pass more than one flag, nor if this is even taking effect, as my script seems to be pulling a page from previous execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd565688(v%3Dvs.85)

```
$brFlgs = 4
$ie.navigate("my-url-here",$brFlgs )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can specify multiple flags by [bitwise-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052782/how-do-i-perform-a-bitwise-or-for-enumerations-in-powershell): `$brFlgs = 2 -bor 4` 
But the first link you referenced says that navNoReadFromCache and navNoWriteToCache are not implemented.